# Only able to upload 5 product images

Tags: magento2

I am only able to see 5 images when adding products.  Is there a configuration somewhere to increase this limitation?[image]

I uploaded 10 images. Only 5 is being displayed. If I was the delete an image there one of the other ones that is not showing gets displayed.  It feels like it is hidden there.

Looking at it with Chrome Inspector, I see that the other images are set as "hidden"
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: there are no such limitations or configuration
however you can check your php limits in ini file, it may have any post_max_size,upload_max_filesize,max_file_uploads limit

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the **Product Details** tab simply limits the view. However, **Images and Videos** tab shows all images uploaded.

More information here: [How to manage product images in Magento 2? (Add/remove)](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-manage-product-images-in-magento-2-addremove/)